# Preencher combobox via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

Tenho o seguinte combobox html:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 row">
   {{ Form::select( 'state',array( 0 => '' ),null, array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-placeholder' => 'State','id' => 'state' ) ) }}
</div>
```

Gostaria de populá-lo com o [Bootstrap + Chosen](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/) com o seguinte bloco em jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            var token = $('#token').val();
            var estados = $('#state');

            $.ajax({
                url : './estados',
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    _token : token
                },
                success : function ( data ) {

                    estados.find('option').remove();
                    estados.append( $('<option>').val( 0 ).text( '' ));
                    //console.log( data );
                    $.each(data, function (i, j) {
                        console.log( j.descricao );
                        var option  = $('<option>').val( j.sigla ).text( j.descricao ) ;
                        estados.append( option );
                    });
                    estados.trigger('chosen:updated');
                }
            });
        });
```

Mas não acontece nada. Sendo que console.log mostra os dados normalmente.

No PHP direto eu consigo popular, mas gostaria usar em laravel.

Comment: já tentou assim `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: Pra que serve o cache : false ?

Comment: Ao configurar a propriedade do cache em falso jQuery irá anexar um carimbo de data / hora ao URL, então o navegador não o armazena em cache (como o URL é exclusivo para cada pedido), se no console está falando que deu certo, as vezes o navegador está guardado no cache as informações

Comment: Não funcionou também

Comment: Só funciona se eu trazer direto do controller

Comment: Nem usando o <select><option> funciona

Comment: Nada? Ainda não consegui resolver

Comment: Consegui preencher via jquery